# JUnit - Specify a test's dependency on other tests (without skipping either)?

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

Our toolkit has over 15000 [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) tests, and many tests are known to fail if some other test fails. For example, if the method X.foo() uses functionality from Y.bar() and YTest.testBar() fails, then XTest.testFoo() will fail too. Obviously, XTest.testFoo() can also fail because of problems specific to X.foo().

While this is fine and I still want both tests run, it would be nice if one could annotate a test dependency with XTest.testFoo() pointing to YTest.testBar(). This way, one could immediately see what functionality used by X.foo() is also failing, and what not.

Is there such annotation available in JUnit or elsewhere? Something like:

```
public XTest {

  @Test
  @DependsOn(method=org.example.tests.YTest#testBar)
  public void testFoo() {
     // Assert.something();
  }

}
```

Comment: Probably "integration-testing" tag was not available (The question is old, hence "unit-testing" was used). Now the tags are fixed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JUnit simply can't yet (at time of writting, 2022).

But both [JExample](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/jexample) and [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) have something like that.

- Said libraries provide their own test runner, which supports their dependency mechanism.
- And both can be used alongside JUnit (without need to rewrite existing classes).
- But TestNG seems more promising.

I don't know how useful it is, but if you try it, please come back to tell us whether it was useful.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like an excellent start: http://chem-bla-ics.blogspot.com/2010/08/specifying-unit-test-dependencies-with.html

Comment: It useful in situation when ClassA.methodA() invokes ClassB.methodB() and both takes a lot of time. In this case you can specify that testMethodA() depends on testMethodB(), that is if testMethodB() fails, testMethodA() also fails **without execution**.

Comment: @Cherry: Sounds like an excuse for not writing [fast tests](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.fi/2009/02/first.html). Some options for improving the design: (1) make methodB fast, (2) make methodA not depend on methodB, (3), use a test double for ClassB when testing ClassA.

Comment: nice link list all answers here, wondering for how long these links stay valid

Answer (score 19):

There's a contribution to JUnit that address this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit.contrib/tree/master/assumes

**Update 2022;** Assumes is out by now, but that only skips tests, which is not what OP asks for.

Comment: This seems not yet available in maven central (see http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjunit-contrib). How do you use it? Or do you use something else now?

Answer (score 7):

org.junit.FixMethodOrder

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
This goes on top of your Unit test class.

You can name your methods public void step1_methodName etc

Comment: Not exactly what was asked. For example in integration tests for Spring Boot, if there are 10 tests and context load fails, I'd like to skip other tests as every single one will try to load context again, so I'd like all to fail if context load failed as first test...

Answer (score 4):

You can declare [test dependencies in TestNG](https://testng.org/#_dependencies_with_annotations), the syntax is almost the same as in your example. I don't think JUnit offers something similar.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There really isn't something like this that I'm aware of.</strike> (Edit: you learn something new every day :)) In my opinion, this isn't that bad of a thing (though I can see it being useful, especially when JUnit it being used for other forms of automated tests - e.g., integration tests). Your tests, IMO, aren't in the strictest sense of the word "unit tests" (at least not the test for `X#foo()`). Tests for `X#foo()` should succeed or fail depending *only* on the implementation of `X#foo()`. It should not be dependent on `Y#foo()`.

What I'd do in your position is to mock out Y, and implement something like `MockY#foo()` with very simple, controlled behavior, and use it in `X#foo()`'s tests.

That said, with 15,000 tests, I can see how this would be a pain to refactor. :)

Comment: I don't see why unit tests cannot have dependencies... our toolkit defines data objects and algorithms... if a data object fails, how do you expect the algorithm to automagically correct for that? Perhaps the naming of both methods foo() was misleading...

Comment: Only strict mock tests would not exhibit any dependencies on each other (and still they may...). In general, such dependencies are always possible and have to reflect dependencies in OO design. I believe that maintaining such annotation across all tests would add to complexity without significant benefit, but having such annotation in a few core cases may benefit.

Comment: Probably "integration-testing" tag was not available (The question is old, hence "unit-testing" was used). Now the tags are fixed, and "mock out Y" makes no sense any longer (because it would be a unit-test not integration-test).

Answer (score 1):

In [behavior driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) library [jBehave](http://jbehave.org/) there's a keyword `GivenScenarios` which imports a list of scenarios that are run before the main scenario. This gives an opportunity to define dependencies and have one point of failure. jBehave's logging will tell you if test fails in dependencies or main body section.