# Test order with espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Is there a way to set test running order in android?
I use Espresso framework and need to test a lot of activities and transitions between them. I want to write different test for those activities, but I need a specific order for running those tests.

Comment: As good testing practice, your tests really should not have an order. You may want to take a step back and analyze your situation.

Comment: @spinster - I agree the unit tests should run in any order however the testing Frameworks now have been extended for Integration/Component as well as Functional tests which most often requires ordering. As an example you would need a database tables to exist before you can component tests CRUD operations. Perhaps we could argue then those frameworks such as Spring, Android Espresso etc should provide such ordering. However that would require altering the core libraries, hence it would be a nice feature to have suite level ordering with in Junit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @spinster said above, you should write your tests in a way where order doesn't matter.

I believe Junit 3 will run tests in alphabetical order of the fully qualified class name, so in theory you could control the order by naming them ( package name, class name, method name ) alphabetically in the order you would like them executed, but I would not recommend that.

See: 
[How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)
[How to pre-define the running sequences of junit test cases？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215285/how-to-pre-define-the-running-sequences-of-junit-test-cases)

Comment: wow...that sounds crazy to me...the test suite could take forever if each test method required its own setup...especially if the setup functionality has already been tested by a previously ran test method..with that methodology, you would be retesting scenarios over and over again just to get to the required states for each given test method...if specifying a test order is a bad idea...forcing alphabetical is an even worse one.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit "crazy" and I would not recommend it, but it was an answer to the question posed.

Comment: I don't agree, what if you are testing api call that store api token in memory (with singleton) and other test access that token. Do you still think that order does not matter?

Answer (score 46):

espresso set running order of tests

From Junit 4.11 comes with @FixMethodOrder annotation. Instead of using custom solutions just upgrade your junit version and annotate test class with FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING). Check the release notes for the details.

Here is a sample:

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {

   @Test
   public void A_firstTest() {
      System.out.println("first");
   }

   @Test
   public void B_secondTest() {
      System.out.println("second");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add annotation as test runner fixture as shown here:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
```

just above class name

Answer (score 6):

You have 3 ways:

---

---

**way 1**: JUnit 4 and 5 work

```
@Test
public void testFunctionMain() {
    test1(); 
    test2()
    test3(); 
}
```

---

**way 2:** JUnit 4 and 5 work

use @FixMethodOrder

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginActivityTest {
}
```

---

**way 3**: Junit5 work

use @Order

```
@Test
@Order(2)
public void testFunction(){
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes You can set order using the order no with the test_name, See the below example-

```
public class MyEspressoTest
        extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<UserLoginActivity> {

    private UserLoginActivity mActivity;

    public MyEspressoTest() {
        super(UserLoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    public void test1InvalidPropigerLogin() {
        // Type text and then press the button.

        //setContentView function to see the layout

        onView(withId(R.id.username))
                .perform(typeText("hill.hacker@gmail.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password))
                .perform(typeText("hhhhh"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.user_login_button)).perform(click());
        // Check that the text was changed.
        onView(withId(R.id.login_status))
                .check(matches(withText("Invalid username or password")));

        //System.out.println("Test pass with invalid user and password");
    }

    public void test2ValidPropigerLogin() {
        // Type text and then press the button.

        onView(withId(R.id.username))
                .perform(typeText("hill.hacker@like.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password))
                .perform(typeText("gggggg"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.user_login_button)).perform(click());

        //System.out.println("Test pass with valid user and password");
    }

    public void test3ForgetPasswordButton() {

        onView(withId(R.id.forgot_pwd_button)).perform(click());

        //onView(isRoot()).perform(ViewActions.pressBack());

        onView(withId(R.id.email_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("hill.hacker@propiger.in"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.reset_password_button)).perform(click());
        // Check that the text was changed.
        onView(withId(R.id.reset_result))
                .check(matches(withText("Email not registered with propiger")));
    }
    public void test4ForgetPasswordButton2() {

        onView(withId(R.id.forgot_pwd_button)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.email_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("Hill.Hacker@like.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.reset_password_button)).perform(click());
        // Check that the text was changed.
        onView(withId(R.id.reset_result))
                .check(matches(withText("Reset password link sent successfully")));
    }
    public void test5RegisterButton() {
        onView(withId(R.id.register_button)).perform(click());

              //onView(isRoot()).perform(ViewActions.pressBack());

        onView(withId(R.id.register_name_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("Hill Hacker"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.register_email_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("Hill.Hacker+888@gmail.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.register_mobileno_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("9090909090"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.register_password_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("password111"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.register_confirm_password_edittext))
                .perform(typeText("password111"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        //onView(withId(R.id.register_country_spinner)).perform(click());
        //onView(isRoot()).perform(withId(R.id.register_country_spinner, Sampling.SECONDS_15));
        onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is("India")))
                .perform(click());

       onView(withId(R.id.register_country_spinner)).check(matches(withText(containsString("India"))));

        onView(withId(R.id.register_button)).perform(click());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I need to test loginActivity test first, if it succeeds , it will login the user.And, then I should test other activities. LogoutActivity test should run at the end. So, sequence of activity test is required.

Comment: you can put some authorization\deauthorization functionality out from the test into specific methods. Then from LoginTest you just call authorization method, from LogoutTest - authorization and then deauthorization. Other tests will then extend some BaseTest which will have authorization in setUp method, and, if needed, deauthorization in tearDown

Answer (score 2):

Add the annotation **@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)** on top of the class name and name the methods in ascending order.

Please see the below links. The answer is there to achieve your need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198659/4675067

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34456810/4675067