# How do I define an order to run junit tests in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, integration-testing

I have a flaky junit test that only fails if I run all my tests.  I think that one test is causing another test to fail, I want to prove it before I try to fix it.

If I run all tests, it runs the "test pollution test" then it runs the "test that fails after test pollution".  It also runs a lot of irrelevant, slow tests in between.  But if I use a pattern to only run these two, it runs "test that fails after test pollution" then "test pollution test".  As a result, both pass.

How do I only run "test pollution test" and "test that fails after test pollution", in that order?

Note: These tests are in separate classes.

Comment: you should fix the test

Comment: @Lashane I need to *know* the problem to fix the test.  This question is about learning what the problem is.

Comment: usually "debugging" is the way to solve it, run all tests, find where it fails, put breakpoint before - find out why it actually fails, what state/variable lead to it, find where this state is changed, put breakpoints and run all tests again

Comment: @Lashane I do that in general, but in this case it's an extremely inefficient way to debug this issue.

Answer (score 34):

According to [JUnit's wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-execution-order):

> By design, JUnit does not specify the execution order of test method
>   invocations. Until now, the methods were simply invoked in the order
>   returned by the reflection API. However, using the JVM order is unwise
>   since the Java platform does not specify any particular order, and in
>   fact JDK 7 returns a more or less random order. Of course,
>   well-written test code would not assume any order, but some do, and a
>   predictable failure is better than a random failure on certain
>   platforms.
>
> From version 4.11, JUnit will by default use a deterministic, but not
>   predictable, order (MethodSorters.DEFAULT). To change the test
>   execution order simply annotate your test class using @FixMethodOrder
>   and specify one of the available MethodSorters:
>
> `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)`: Leaves the test methods in the
>   order returned by the JVM. This order may vary from run to run.
>
> `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`: Sorts the test methods
>   by method name, in lexicographic order.

You could use `MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING` and change your method names to match with your specific order. I know you're using this just for debugging sake but it's a **Test Smell** to rely on your test methods execution order and JUnit does not provide more finer grain control over test methods execution order

Comment: Cool, that's helpful. In the end, I just manually put @Ignore on everything (temporarily)

Comment: This doesn't help this scenario because this problem spans multiple classes.

Answer (score 7):

As said by Ali Dehghani, You can order the test method execution by

> @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING): Sorts the test methods
>   by method name, in lexicographic order.

**Code:**

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ApplicationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    void t1AttachUI(){
        // testing code goes here
    }

    @Test
    void t2InitializeViews(){
        // testing code goes here
    };

    @Test
    void t3SettingValues(){
        // testing code goes here
    };

    @Test
    void t4Validation(){
        // testing code goes here
    };

    @Test
    void t3AfterButtonPress(){
        // testing code goes here
    };
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help this scenario because this problem spans multiple classes.

Comment: Naming t1, t2, ... working only up to t9. Naming t01, t02, ... working up to t99.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests ought to be independent so most frameworks don't guarantee or enforce the order in which they are run. But since you want to enforce an order the easiest way I've done it in the past it to create a "throw away" test suite or test method that calls the tests in whatever order I want them to run in. Unit tests are methods, just call them. This is easy to do if you're dealing with tens of tests, not at all appealing if you're dealing with hundreds or thousands.

Try to isolate the flaky interaction as much as possible, then swap around the order of the poorly interacting tests within the throwaway calling method.

Answer (score 1):

In *JUnit 5* (from version [5.8.0](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/release-notes/) onwards) test classes can be ordered too.

*src/test/resources/**junit-platform.properties**:*

```
# ClassOrderer$OrderAnnotation sorts classes based on their @Order annotation
junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$OrderAnnotation
```

Other Junit built-in class orderer implementations:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$ClassName
org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$DisplayName
org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random
```

You can also provide your own orderer. It must implement ClassOrderer interface:

```
package foo;
public class MyOrderer implements ClassOrderer {
    @Override
    public void orderClasses(ClassOrdererContext context) {
        Collections.shuffle(context.getClassDescriptors());
    }
}
```

```
junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=foo.MyOrderer
```

**Note that `@Nested` test classes cannot be ordered by a `ClassOrderer`.**

Refer to JUnit 5 [documentations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-test-execution-order) and ClassOrderer [API docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/ClassOrderer.html) to learn more about this.

source: [JUnit test class order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624495/junit-test-class-order)

I recommend paying attention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269239/10663941

method order: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-test-order (because I got here in search of an answer)

Comment: This doesn't help this scenario because this problem spans multiple classes.

Comment: @DanielKaplan i am updated answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. Can you include an example of using the `MyOrderer` in two separate test classes?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a handy tip

You can define the run order in intellij for a run configuration by Ctrl-clicking each test class in the order you want to run them then right clicking the class and selecting run tests (Ctrl+Shift+F10). If you inspect the run configuration it will be using "Pattern" as the resource type with a value that has the classes in the order you selected them:

```
com.example.Test1Class||com.example.Test2Class||com.example.Test3Class
```

This should help you confirm the theory about test pollution