# Display test results in Intellij in same order as defined in test method

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

When running Junit 4 tests on Intellij (Community 2023.2), I'd like the results to be displayed in the order the tests are defined in the test method.

The results are displayed in a random order, which I guess correspond to the order in which the tests are executed. So perhaps it is possible the change the display order by changing the execution order with @OrderWith or @FixMethodOrder. However, I don't like this approach because firstly, what I actually want to change is the display, not execution order, and secondly, the aformentioned annotations don't provide a ready-to-use implementation of the order I want.

Is there a simple Intellij setting for changing this display order that I'm not aware of?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456739/how-do-i-define-an-order-to-run-junit-tests-in-intellij

Comment: there's also a request feature for IDEA for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304144