# Espresso, Run TestClasses in Order

Tags: android-espresso

I'm testing an app with espresso.
The 1st testcase loads data with the 1st activity from the web into a local database.
The 2nd test case / 2. Activity shows data from the database.

That's why Testcase 1 needs to run before Testcase 2. But that does not always happen, espresso occasionally changes the order.
How can I solve the problem? Can I set the order of the TestCases (Testclasses)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following annotation @FixMethodOrder.

You can use it with the following parameter : MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING.

The code (an example) :

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class YourTestClass {

   @Test
   public void A_Test() {
      System.out.println("1");
   }

   @Test
   public void B_Test() {
      System.out.println("2");
   }
}
```

You will find more detailed solutions here : [previous answers] ([Test order with espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308301/test-order-with-espresso))

---

You can do that using the @RunWith annotation. You can have a short look here [Aggregating tests in suites](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/aggregating-tests-in-suites). Basically what you have to do is the following :

Edit:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)  
@Suite.SuiteClasses({  
    TestFeature1.class,  
    TestFeature2.class,  
    TestFeature3.class,  
    TestFeature4.class  
})  
public class FeatureTestSuite {  
// the class remains empty,  
// used only as a holder for the above annotations  
}
```

Comment: I mean, different classes:

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class first_Test...

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class second_Test...


Is that even possible, or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: You can do that using the @RunWith annotation. You can have a short look here [Aggregating tests in suites](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/aggregating-tests-in-suites). Basically what you have to do is the following : `@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  TestFeature1.class,
  TestFeature2.class,
  TestFeature3.class,
  TestFeature4.class
}) 
public class FeatureTestSuite {
  // the class remains empty,
  // used only as a holder for the above annotations
}`

Comment: And how do you create a coverage report for this test suite?